# Finding rendered files affected by a source change in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am writing a script which I would like to be able to determine the set of rendered files that changes to the Jekyll source would affect. For example, given the path to a `.md` file in my input to Jekyll, I'd like to find the `.html` file in the build output that the markdown was rendered to. Similarly, if I am looking at a file that is included as a template in other files (or a layout), I would like to take into account the fact that multiple other files use the content from the single input file and have my script return all of those files. How can I do this?

I am aware that I could diff the Jekyll output between two different builds, but I would rather not run an extra build if I don't have to. I expect that this will involve a Ruby script that calls into Jekyll.

My goal is to be able to diff a range of commits in git and find the output files that were changed, but the fact that the list of files is coming from git shouldn't matter; I can easily extract the list from a git diff.

Comment: Did you know `jekyll serve --incremental` ?

Comment: If your goal is to find changes originated by git commits, why dont you include the "built" (rendered) files in git as well?

Comment: @DavidJacquel yes, I am aware of the incremental option. I'm hoping that I can call that same logic that determines what needs to be rebuilt for use in my script.

Comment: @Felix checking in the build output (regardless of the language) creates many known problems. You need to remember to update the build before committing (which would be difficult for new contributors), so it isn't guaranteed to be correct. The compiled files also obscure diffs, especially when you change a template used on many pages.

Comment: If you want to mimic jekyll incremental, you can have a look at [jekyll regenerator class](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/regenerator.rb).